# Add a .gitignore file to every commit

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a git repo that was converted from SVN. It lacks a `.gitignore` file.

Of course, I could just add one and commit it on `main`, but it would be better if it were present also on other branches and all the tags.

So I wonder if there is a good way to rewrite the entire history, adding a `.gitignore` to each and every commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `.gitignore` file in a new commit, then perform an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i --root`) and place the commit as the very first. Then, rebase all other branches onto the branch (if you want to preserve any existing merge commits, use `--rebase-merges` when doing this).

N.B. this implies rewriting git's history (which will result in new commit hashes).